# How to get the current bean when iterating over a JRBeanCollectionDataSource in Jasper Reports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The Jasper Reports docs is silent on this issue and the JRDataSource interface is not explicitly allowing the access to the current bean. The current bean handle is very useful if you want to call some non property method.

The only solution I've found so far looking in the jasper reports sources is to use a _THIS field in the report and invoke the desired method on it:

```
${_THIS}.computeSomeValue()
```

Is there a better, more standard approach?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a custom_Scriptlet extending the JRDefaultScriptlet (if i ever need any other method calls pertaining to my bean). A better approach i think will be just to gather all data you will ever need (either in your bean as an instance variable with a setter/getter method or passed as a parameter when you fill your report).

This way you can leave the property bean methods take care of the rest.

Comment: Most of the time, yes, the best approach is to prepare your data before filling the report. But there are some cases when a handle on the current bean makes live easier. For example when you know the bean properties at run time, not at report compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.getData().get($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1)